# Kivymd Swiper position problems

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

The problem is that the images move when swiping.
Does anyone perhaps have more experience in this area?

If I don't write the class ThemeWindow in the TabPanel, everything works but unfortunately I don't know why. I've already tried one.

```
<ThemeSwiper@MDSwiperItem>


<ThemeWindow>:

    MDSwiper:
        id: Swiper
        size_hint: 1, 0.5
        size_hint_min: 0.5, 0.5
        pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
        on_swipe_right: root.swipe_right()
        on_swipe_left: root.swipe_left()
        items_spacing: 20


        ThemeSwiper:
            FitImage:
                size_hint_max: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                size_hint_min: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                source: "testbild.png"
                radius: [20,]


        ThemeSwiper:
            FitImage:
                size_hint_max: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                size_hint_min: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                source: "testbild.png"
                radius: [20,]

        ThemeSwiper:
            FitImage:
                size_hint_max: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                size_hint_min: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                source: "testbild.png"
                radius: [20,]

        ThemeSwiper:
            FitImage:
                size_hint_max: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                size_hint_min: root.width - dp(40), root.height
                source: "testbild.png"
                radius: [20,]

<TabPanel>
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_pos: "top_left"
    tab_size: "1, 1"

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Game"

        GameSettings:

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Stats"

        Stats:

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: "Themes"

        ThemeWindow:
```

I have already tried to solve the problem with items_spacing and size_hint but without success.